# pattern to add a specific command to HISTIGNORE . The command includes 2 words with one ore more spaces

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wish to add a specific command to HISTIGNORE. The command includes 2 words with one or more spaces between. Please suggest a pattern for the same.
I am not sure how to add logic to include multiple spaces. Currently I am using this and it is only considering one space

```
HISTIGNORE="word1 word2*"
```

Comment: `HISTIGNORE="word1 *"` will ignore the `word1` commands with any number of arguments

Comment: @Fravadona I specifically want word1 word2 to be disabled. Because I want the history to be logged for all other combinations, for example word1 word3, etc

Comment: Then there's no other choice than to use an extglob: `HISTIGNORE='word1+( )word2?( )*'`